# How to get all the nodes which are coming after a particular tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have the following HTML structure and I want to find all siblings and nodes below which appear after `<div>xyz</div>` till the last node of HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page-container">
     <div id="page-1">
       <p> abc <p>
       <div>xyz</div>
       <p>bbb</p>
       <b>hhhh</b>
     </div>
     <div  id="page-2">
      <p>hhhh</p>
      <span>abc</span>
      <p> gggg </p>
     </div>
     <div  id="page-3">
      <p>hhhh</p>
      <span>abc</span>
      <p> gggg </p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I used

```
xpath('//div[contains(text(), "xyz")]/following-sibling::*')
```

but it's not returning all the nodes, it's giving only `<p>bbb</p><b>hhhh</b>` nodes.

I am expecting the following output:

```
<div id="page-container">
  <div id="page-1">
     <div>xyz</div>
      <p>bbb</p>
      <b>hhhh</b>
     </div>
   <div  id="page-2">
     <p>hhhh</p>
     <span>abc</span>
     <p> gggg </p>
   </div>
   <div  id="page-3">
     <p>hhhh</p>
     <span>abc</span>
     <p> gggg </p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

How do I fetch all the nodes appearing after a particular node?

Comment: What do you mean by "all" here? Should it include all the parents of `<div>xyz</div` too (because their closing tag is after it)?

Comment: yes I want all the parents of <div>xyz</div> but don't want  `<div id="page-1"> <p> abc <p>` this html

Comment: Could you please add the exact output you want in your question?

Comment: @Dogbert I have added the output

Comment: I did by using following steps: `doc.xpath('//div[@id="page-container"]').xpath('//div[contains(text(), "xyz")]/preceding-sibling::*').remove` . You can suggest more better option.

Answer (score 0):

One of the hardest things about extracting information from HTML or XML is determining where to start the capture. It's usually easier to start above the desired node and work down if you want to capture a lot of similar nodes, then remove what you don't want, than it is to work piecemeal and try to rebuild some structure.

I'd do this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page-container">
     <div id="page-1">
       <p> abc <p>
       <div>xyz</div>
       <p>bbb</p>
       <b>hhhh</b>
     </div>
     <div  id="page-2">
      <p>hhhh</p>
      <span>abc</span>
      <p> gggg </p>
     </div>
     <div  id="page-3">
      <p>hhhh</p>
      <span>abc</span>
      <p> gggg </p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

page_container = doc.at('#page-container')
page1 = page_container.at('#page-1')
page1.children = page1.children[3..-1]
```

Which results in:

```
puts page_container.to_html
# >> <div id="page-container">
# >>      <div id="page-1">
# >> <div>xyz</div>
# >>        <p>bbb</p>
# >>        <b>hhhh</b>
# >>      </div>
# >>      <div id="page-2">
# >>       <p>hhhh</p>
# >>       <span>abc</span>
# >>       <p> gggg </p>
# >>      </div>
# >>      <div id="page-3">
# >>       <p>hhhh</p>
# >>       <span>abc</span>
# >>       <p> gggg </p>
# >>      </div>
# >>     </div>
```

Note:

- I'm using CSS selectors, rather than XPath. CSS is almost always more readable; XPath has more power but that comes at the price of readability.
- I use an offset into the "page-1" div to skip the first three nodes: There's a text node, the `<p>` node followed by another text node:

  ```
  page_container.at('#page-1').children[0,3]
  # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdb6d196b48 "\n       ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdb6d1979a8 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdb6d1b7d48 " abc ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdb6d1b7af0 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdb6d1b7870 "\n       ">]>]
  ```
- I'd normally use a `remove` to get rid of `<p> abc <p>` but I'm seeing what looks like a bug in Nokogiri 1.6.6.2 that results in:

  ```
  page_container.at('#page-1 p').remove

  puts page_container.to_html
  # >> <div id="page-container">
  # >>      <div id="page-1">
  # >>        <p>
  # >>        </p>
  # >> <div>xyz</div>
  ```

  A bug-report has been created for this.